# mlPushMenu : Maintain State of last visited after collapse or redirected

Tags: jquery, menu

I have implemented **mlPushMenu** from [github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu/tree/master/js](http://github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu/tree/master/js) as shown below:

```
new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), document.getElementById( 'trigger' ), {
type : 'cover'} );
```

Now I am opening submenu of it and then click on link which redirects me to another page of application. After redirected to that page, If I open my menu then it is opening like first initialization state
every time. But I want to open the menu with previous state(Expand/collapse) before the redirection.

Please help me out !!

Comment: Is this the library you're having trouble with? - https://github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu/tree/master/js - And if it is, can you edit the question to make that clear?

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your quick response. And yes, this is the library. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You'd probably have to do two things. First, you want to set the URL so the new page will know what state the menu was in. Then, with Javascript, you'll want to trigger a click event on the menu reset the state of the menu. i.e. (with JQuery) $("#mp-menu").trigger("click").

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It wont work for me. and finally I have implemented my own logic in _openMenu(). And working fine !!

Comment: By all means, answer your own question and share your solution, to help anyone else who runs into the same problem!